# Define a binary operation and prove as a group

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let $\mathbb R$ be the set of all real numbers and $H = \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. Define a binary operation $\circ$ on $H$ as follows 
$(p,q) \circ (r,s) = (pr,ps+q)$, where $(p,q),(r,s) \in H$? Is $(H, \circ )$ a group?

Comment: What do you mean "how to define"? In what respect does what you write doffer from what can be called a definition?

Comment: I just want to prove that  $(H, \circ )$ a group.

Comment: @Rokai Do you know what axioms a group satisfies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this is a group, you need to check all the axioms of a group.  You need an identity, so can you find an element $(x,y)$ such that $(p,q)\circ (x,y)=(p,q)=(x,y)\circ(p,q)$.  If you expand out the $\circ$'s it should be easy to figure out what $x$ and $y$ need to be.  Then look for the inverse of a general element $(p,q)$.  Then see if associativity is satisfied.

Comment: Actually i'm having difficulties around expanding $(p,q)\circ (x,y)=(p,q)=(x,y)\circ(p,q)$. Can you please help me? I'm new to this kind of problems.

Comment: You plug it into the definition of $\circ$.  So $(p,q)\circ(x,y)=(px,py+q)$.  Now to have this equal to $(p,q)$ you need $p=px, py+q=q$ What does that tell you about $x,$ and $y?$  Does it work on the other side?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the identity of the group and show not all elements have inverse in the group.